# WCF known types

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a question about derived classes in WCF.

In the program we have the following classes:

```
public interface IExampleProgram
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    A GetData(Request request);
}

public class ExampleProgram: IExampleProgram
{
  public A GetData(Request request)
  {
    B b = new B();
    return b; //would expect the result to be the base class
  }
}

[DataContract(Name="Hello")]
public class B:A
{
}

public class A
{
}
```

But this not seem to work. My request ends up in an error.
Not entirely clear to me why this is not possible.

After reading some topics about WCF, I added the KnownType attribute to the interface.
So the interface looks like:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(B))]
public interface IExampleProgram
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    A GetData(Request request);
}
```

However, in the result I now have "Hello" exposed as type.
I.e.

```
<GetData i:type="Hello">
```

Would there be a way to avoid this?
Is there a more easy way to just return the base class instead of having to adjust the contract?

Comment: `[DataContract(Name="A")]` ... then on client side there will be no need for `B` class definition

Comment: go fof `Name=nameof(A)` it's better for refactoring

Comment: I think you can use the message contract, which allows you to specify the precise structure of the SOAP message you need. For more information about message contract, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts